# An older book, 20+ years back minimum. A guy lives on a spaceship that was grown

Tags: story-identification

So, a grown spaceship. The earth is forbidden and lots of rumors abound about it being a death trap. The grown tools have a name they go under, which I can't remember. The guy has a dictionary or encyclopedia that is, I believe, a cheetah that had been grown. This guy finds a girl and they both make it to earth, find out it isn't a deathtrap and they can live there at the end. The dictionary or encyclopedia cat survives there as well, but none of the grown things that were made for space can survive on earth. There was a battle where they were firing live ordinance at each other... I don't think I remember anything else...

Comment: *They* were firing live ordinance at eoch other? Who's they, the guy and the girl?

Comment: The living starship the guy was on, I don't remember if he had found the girl yet. Um, I think it was space pirates? All I really remember is it talking about how this ammo had claws or something to cut muscles on the other ship(s), maybe they described other ammo types?

Comment: Not otherwise a match, but Octavia Butler's "Xenogenesis" series features living spaceships.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[The Helix and the Sword](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/4811181)** by John C. McLoughlin

Six thousand years in the future mankind lives in organic space habitats. Planets are shunned because according to the Church, gravity is evil. Earth is especially avoided because it is rumored to be especially deadly, This is actually true since people living in Space have no immunity against all the diseases of Earth.

The main character, Dyson Tessier, has a mobile encyclopedia named Pantalog five, that was genetically engineered to look like a cheetah.

The space peoples have access to abundant supplies of energy (Solar Power) but are impoverished with respect to matter (because planets & moons are evil and all the asteroids were claimed six thousand years ago)

This is the opposite of current day Earth, which has abundant matter, but not enough energy (because there are no space industries and all the oil and uranium ran out)

The main character and his Lady Fair must

1. Demonstrate that people can live on Earth (after painfully gaining immunity to disease the hard way) and harvest matter
2. Break the monopoly on power held by the corrupt aristocracy and the conniving genetic engineers.